# Being able to push and pull on multiple github emails/accounts, permission denied (publickey, keyboard-interactive)

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab

I think I could just use some clarification on how to go about getting my computer to work with a second github email for pushing/pulling.

I have a personal github account that I've been using, and a new gitlab work account that I'm trying to set up. I have a personal ssh key stored at`~/.ssh/id_rsa` and a work ssh key stored in `~/.ssh/id_work`. The personal ssh key is on my personal github, the work ssh key is on my work gitlab account.

I'm trying to set up pushing and pulling via the commandline  I created a directory `workdir/` and ran

```
git init
git remote add
git config --local user.name "<gitlab username>"
git config --local user.email "<gitlab email>"
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_work"
git pull
```

But I always get the following error:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried editing my `~/.ssh/config` file to specify the paths of the two ssh keys for both hosts like so

```
# GITHUB
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# GITLAB
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
```

But I'm still getting this error. I'm not sure what I'm forgetting to do here.

Comment: Have you copied `id_work.pub` to Gitlab? What does `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_work -Tv git@gitlab.com` ?

Comment: @phd ah sorry. I tried updating my ssh key again and that seemed to be the solution, now it's pushing and pulling. I thought it was updated already... But also that ssh command is very useful, thank you.